# How to post on facebook with tag friends using api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, postman

I am trying to post on facebook and tags friends using api .I am using api as

URL = https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=xxx & message=hi &tags=user1,user2

METhod = POST

Using this i post successfully but friends is not tagged in post. Can any help me how can i post on facebook and taggged friends using graph api.

Comment: what is the response form the api?

Comment: @luschn  return response is { "id": "245644289110436_321549978186533" }

Comment: and how did you get the user ids for tagging?

Comment: @luschn i get user id using me/feed and using this user id i can post also but not tag in post

Comment: i mean, how do you get the friend ids, for the tags parameter?

Comment: I am made two account and made friends each other now using me/feed and get userId of both account

Comment: that´s not how it works. check out my answer. btw, you are not allowed to use two facebook accounts, only one account per user is allowed. for testing, there are test users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tagging, try using the tagging tokens you get with `/me/taggable_friends`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends/

...or App Scoped IDs of friends who authorized your App.

Update:

> This endpoint is deprecated.

Comment: why the downvote? is there anything wrong with the answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote but its deprecated now!